# How to Combine Date and Time in Between Clause in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to Combine Date (in Column) and Time (in Stored Procedure) in Between Clause in a Stored Procedure
 @EndTime seems to work but when I add a column StoreDate then parameter @starttime it doesn't work

```
 @StartTime      DATETIME,
 @EndTime       DATETIME,
```

My Query

```
 WHERE CONVERT(varchar, enddate,108) between CAST(CONVERT(date, a.StoreDate ) + @StartTime AS DATE) AND @EndTime
```

Comment: Why are you converting a date to varchar to then compare with dates? Anyway [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51443/7257) covers how to combine a date and a time to make a datetime2. You would end up with something like `WHERE enddate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, a.StoreDate), @StartTime) AND @EndTime;`  I would also advise to be [cautious when using `BETWEEN` for date range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Converting to VARCHAR before a date comparison will give you results you do not expect.

Comment: not working thanks anyways